# Beating conservative at working in alien area: one liberal success to start with (3,1,4,5)

Tags: cryptic-clues, crosswords, cryptic-crosswords

Struggling with this one. I know alien is normally ET and conservative is probably C or tory but can't figure out what the definition is. The letters I have so far are _ _ _ /O/_ I _ E / _ _ _ _ _ (Not entirely sure about the O either)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your letters are correct, and the answer is:

> **CAT O'NINE TAILS**

Why?

> "Beating" is the definition here and the remainder of this clue is just a string of short words and abbreviations which form the phrase "**[CAT O'NINE TAILS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_o%27_nine_tails)**", i.e. the multi-tailed whip used as a punishment, 'designed to lacerate the skin and cause intense pain' (*Wikipedia*).
>
>  As you suggest, 'conservative' gives us '**C**' and we use the whole word '**AT**' next. 'Working' is '**ON**', then we have '**IN**'. 'Alien' (again, as you rightly suggest) is '**E.T.**', then 'area' gives us '**A**'. We then have 'one' ('**I**' in Roman numerals), 'liberal' ('**L**') and 'success to start with' (i.e. the first letter of 'success', namely '**S**').

Altogether:

> *Beating* (clue) conservative (**C**) at (**AT**) working (**ON**) in (**IN**) alien (**ET**) area (**A**): one (**I**) liberal (**L**) success to start with (**S**) = **CAT O'NINE TAILS**.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much for your explanation